# Is array generated by CopyTo() still reference to its parent memory?

Tags: c#, deep-copy, datagridviewrow

I want deepcopy of DataGridViewRows.
I have an DataGridViewRow array generated by DataGridView.Rows.CopyTo() function.
Is the array dgvra still reference to the same memory as items in DataGridView.Rows?

DGV_Comp is a DataGridView Control

```
DataGridViewRow[] dgvra = new DataGridViewRow[DGV_Comp.Rows.Count];
DGV_Comp.Rows.CopyTo(dgvra, 0);
```

From Variable watch, this is what I found

[1. Both equivalent cells are 1.357](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Fng.png)

[2. Chanage cell in DGV_Comp to 2.468===>Counterpart cell in dgvra also changed to 2.468](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2V6U.png)

[3. Chanage cell in DGV_Comp to 3.579===>Counterpart cell in dgvra also changed to 3.579](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyoJ4.png)

[4. Clear all rows in DGV_Comp ===> Cell in dgvra changed backed to 1.357](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGl8E.png)

Can anyone help to get a reasonable explanation for what I found?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does it matter? C# is a managed language, for the most part it should not matter if it is the same memory location or not, that is an implementation detail of the runtime.

Comment: `object.GetHashCode()` should tell you if it is a reference to the same object (i.e. if the HashCode is the same)

Comment: `DataGridView` should only be display mechanism. Keep data in `DataTable` and there you can copy, etc

Comment: It is not a deep copy, the array elements still reference the same row objects.  Get ahead with DataGridViewRow.Clone().